# Sub-relationship in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Currently I've got 3 models, **Listing**, **Offer** & **Payment** which have the following relationships:

**Listing**

```
class Listing extends Model {

    public function offers() {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Offer::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

}
```

**Offer**

```
class Offer extends Model {

    public function payment() {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Payment::class, 'item_id', 'id')->where('item_type', \App\Models\Offer::class)->where('status', '1');
    }

    public function listing() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Listing::class)->withTrashed();
    }

}
```

Payment

```
class Payment extends Model {

    public function offer() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Offer::class, 'item_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
    }

}
```

How can I go from them **Listing** model & return a relationship with the payments table directly?

**Listing** can have unlimited amounts of **Offer** but **Offer** can only have 1 max **Payment**

To find any corresponding payment information, I'm having to query the **Offer** based on the `listing_id` within the model, and then access the `Offer->payment`, when I'd much prefer to be able to just do something like this:

```
$transaction_id = $id;

$listing = Listing::whereHas('payment', function($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('transaction_id', $id);
        $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`HasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through):

```
public function payments() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Payment::class, Offer::class, null, 'item_id')
        ->where('payments.item_type', Offer::class)
        ->where('payments.status', '1')
        ->orderBy('offers.created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I attempted to use the following but appears to be failing for me & returning no rows

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: `$listing = Listing::whereHas('payments', function ($q) use($id) {
            $q->where('payments.user_id', Auth::user()->id);
            $q->where('payments.transaction_id', Crypt::decrypt($id));
        })->first();`
That's how I'm attempting to use it?

Comment: Please replace `first()` with `toSql()` and post the result.

Comment: `select * from listings where exists (select * from payments inner join offers on offers.id = payments.item_id where offers.deleted_at is null and listings.id = offers.listing_id and payments.user_id = '3' and payments.transaction_id = '69D20243XW764905K' and offers.deleted_at is null and payments.item_type = 'App\Models\Offer' and payments.status = '1') and listings.deleted_at is null limit 1` I've checked each condition 1 by 1 & they all appear to be valid? although running this query manually returns 0 results